# Uploading files and other data from Android through Http POST request

Tags: java, android, post, http-post

This is a simple way of posting files from Android.

```
String url = "http://yourserver.com/upload.php";
File file = new File("myfileuri");
try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);
    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    //Do something with response...

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

What I want to do is add more `POST` variables to my request. How do I do that? While uploading plain strings in `POST` request, we use `URLEncodedFormEntity`.

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Whereas while uploading files, we use `InputStreamEntity`.

Also, how do I specifically upload this file to `$_FILES['myfilename']`?

Comment: try using asynctask..you can use a hashmap if you want to upload different types of variables

Comment: obviously I will use asynctask. and yes usually hashmap of name value pairs is used for sending multiple variables. But, the entity types for String and File are different. That confuses me.

Comment: use multipart request

Comment: making multipart is not the doubt. i want to send normal strings along with files to the same php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few ways for you:

- make 2 post requests: first with image File. Server returns an image id, and with second request you attach to this id yours params.
- or, instead of the '2 request' solution, you could use `MultipartEntity` request. [Look here for more datails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017414/post-multipart-request-with-android-sdk)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend the first suggestion. If you make two requests and either one of those fails, it can spell disaster for your data.

Comment: yeah, i do not recomend too, but there is such solution. I used the second one, it's much better

Answer (score 1):

the most effective method is to use [android-async-http](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

You can use this code to upload file :

```
 

    File myFile = new File("/path/to/file.png");
    RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
    try {
        params.put("profile_picture", myFile);
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {}
```

Comment: can I upload any kind of files using this Library and not have to specify mi e type

Comment: Yes. YOu can upload any kind of files

Comment: My advice is: stay away from loopj.
I've used it for way too long, and it sucks in supporting SSL. It's been a known bug for a long time and apparently it can't been fixed due to the infrastructure used in the library. 
Use volley or retrofit/simplehttp instead.

Answer (score 1):

After spending a full day found [loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/). You can follow this code sample:

```
//context: Activity context, Property: Custom class, replace with your pojo
public void postProperty(Context context,Property property){
        // Creates a Async client. 
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
         //New File
        File files = new File(property.getImageUrl());
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        try {
            //"photos" is Name of the field to identify file on server
            params.put("photos", files);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            //TODO: Handle error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //TODO: Reaming body with id "property". prepareJson converts property class to Json string. Replace this with with your own method 
        params.put("property",prepareJson(property));
        client.post(context, baseURL+"upload", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                System.out.print("Failed..");
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                System.out.print("Success..");
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to **upload files** from your app, here is a good tutorial for you:

[**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](http://stunningco.de/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

If you want to upload strings as well, I think you already know the solution :)

Comment: hey Akash! thanks for your answer but it still did not answer my question. If you did not get my doubt, this question is exactly the same.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598457/android-how-to-send-song-file-to-server-throught-httppost-along-with-other-vari?rq=1
unfortunately this is unsolved too :(

Comment: okay i got it here are some questions with answers for your type of problem:<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949504/android-uploading-a-file-to-a-page-along-with-other-post-strings>   

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965022/android-upload-file-with-filling-out-post-body-together/9003674#9003674>